# Jquery - change img src on click and return old src if clicked on different img or block

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to change image src on click and return it's old src if clicked on different image or block

```
    <div>
     <img src="a" />
     <img src="b" />
     <img src="c" />
     </div>
```

suppose i click on img with src="a" or src="b" i want it to change it to src="d" when i click on img with src="c", change back the src of the previous image to src="a" or src="b" which was on intial stage.

```
 $('img').click(function() {
     Imgsrc = $('img').attr("src");
     $('img.current').removeClass('current').attr("src", eval("Imgsrc"));
     $(this).closest('img').addClass('current');
     $('img.current').attr("src", "d");
 });
```

it is changing color of src="a" to src="c". I know because i am initializing first but then how to save it first and then change. Might be silly question but still need help.

Comment: `<img src="a"></img>` is invalid, `<img src="a">` is a self closing tag

Comment: @Magicprog.fr Just edited :]

Comment: @Magicprog.fr then actually consider closing it ``<img src="a" />``

Comment: you could use data attributes to store the alternative src and swap them out

Comment: The image has to be loaded on every click...Just add the image in the html and hide/show images on click.

Comment: Sorry, it just an example actual data is being generated dynamically so there can be any no of img tags not just 3. Wanted to know how to save and change src on click

Comment: @seahorsepip <img src=""> is valid HTML5 and it is absolutely fine without closing it with a /. It is a so-called void element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest you use the [$('object').data()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/) method to store the values in the images.

This way you store the values in the objects themselves, and you can easely swap in and out information.

```js
$('img').on('click',function() {
  var tradeoff = 'http://firestarter.firebrandgroup.com/images/flame-logo.gif?b20388';
  /** Reset images to original image **/
  $('img').each(function() {
    var $img = $(this);
    /** get the old original src **/
    var data = $img.data('oldsrc');
    /** only update if there is actually some value there **/
    if(data) {
      $img.attr('src',data);
      }
      
  });
  
  /** current image **/
  var $this = $(this);
  /** current href **/
  var src = $this.attr('src');
  
  /** only store if different from tradeoff value **/
  if(src != tradeoff) {
    /** store in image the old data **/
    $this.data('oldsrc',src);
  }
  /** show the tradeoff **/
  $this.attr('src',tradeoff);
});
```

```css
img { width:100px;height:60px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/RTfvXkEXa-k/maxresdefault.jpg"><BR/>
<img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/XlUPuj2V6PM/maxresdefault.jpg"><BR/>
<img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Haj9TAFCv5w/maxresdefault.jpg"><BR/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use html data attributes.

```
  <div>
     <img src="a" data-source="a"/>
     <img src="b" data-source="b" />
     <img src="c" data-source="c" />
     </div>


function reset_img()
{
    var images = $('img');
    $.each(images, function() {
        var image = $(this);
        if(image.attr("src") != image.attr("data-source"))
             image.attr("src") = image.attr("data-source");
    }
}

$('img').on('click',function(e) {
     reset_img();
     $(this).attr("src", "d");
 });
```